# Daylight And Standard Time Not Equal Timespan Yet Works Out

Tags: time

I have been thinking about this for a long time now, and no one can answer it. I forget the exact length span, however, the span for each is not equal. For example, DST is 120 days, and "standard" time is 245 days. It would seem, since DST and Standard time do not cancel out (for every +1 hour, there is a -1 hour), clock time and "nature" time, would not be in sync (AM would be night, and PM would be day).

How heck does this work out in the end?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! (Take the **[Tour]!**) I'm glad you got the answer to the question that was puzzling to you, but a puzzling question is not always a *Puzzle*. It's great that you're eager to contribute here but this question isn't on topic for Puzzling.SE.  You may benefit from looking around the site, and in particular checking out the high voted puzzles in the tags that appeal to you, to get a better sense of what kinds of puzzles work best here. Welcome again, and hope your next posting sees great success!

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it does not present an actual puzzle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't actually have to add up in any way.

The idea is that, depending on your location on the globe, sunrise and sunset shift with the seasons.

In some places, this can cause a real problem.  In the northern United States, the days get pretty short in the winter.  If you don't adjust the clock, you end up with children standing on bus stops (often on **very** narrow roads) before the sun is up.  To avoid this danger, the clock gets shifted back one hour, and now they have one more hour into the new day, to have more light when people will be out on the road.

Of course, this "steals" an hours from the end of the day, as the sun sets an hour "earlier."  That's where your "cancel-out" math belongs.  On an individual day, not on the system overall.

Comment: OK, that makes sense, looking at the big picture i just could not figure it out. BTW, I do live in one of the areas, I am a bit south of Buffalo NY, in the middle of nowhere, where we are happy to have paved roads LOL.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply you don't have paved roads.  But I'm originally from the suburbs of Oklahoma City.  I moved to Bethel, Connecticut when I was 12, and two things that astonished me were 1) how much more narrow the roads were, and 2) how much the daylight seemed to have shifted by just going a few hundred miles.  Farmers complain about the DLT time shift, but they seem to complain far more down here in Oklahoma, where the shift in light level is not so dramatic.

Comment: No I am very proud of being a country boy =). I tried a city life, cannot take people being around me 24/7. Yes the farmers out here feel the same way, and get angry about the myths that DST is because of them, or no school in the summer because of them. I found it, kind of funny since snow is on its way soon.